# Spring Security Authentication manager autowiring

Tags: spring, security, authentication, autowired

after few desperate hours trying to find out why is not my custom authentication manager autowiring, I came here for a little help.
So I've got Web application, running on Spring (with Stripes). Authentication is done by my custom class. Everything works fine - in jsp, i can use jsp tags and everyting, http interceptor works as it should. But when i try to autowire authentication manager into Jersey "REST class" , everything goes wrong and nothing is injected.

So, in web xml i've got both context files:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security" />
<context:annotation-config/>

<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">

</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="AuthenticationManagerBean" />
</authentication-manager> 

<beans:bean id="AuthenticationManagerBean" class="com.manager.services.MyAuthenticationManager"/>
<beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

And inside of Jersey action bean is something like this:

```
@Inject
@Qualifier("authManager")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

The whole application builds ok, jetty server start without problems (both MyAuthenticationManager and org.springframework.security.authenticationManager are succesfully pre-instatiated), but when try to use autowired authmanager, im getting null pointer.

**EDIT:**
I have succesfully autowired AuthenticationManager into Stripes' Action Beans, but there is still problem with Jersey's action beans, where construction @Inject @Qualifier(...) doesnt work for AuthManager (but works for other autowired beans, altough without @Qualifier, just @Inject).

**EDIT 2:**
After few hours trying to find out why Spring doesn't inject authenticationManager into Jersey Beans, I solved the problem with:

```
@Inject
@InjectParam("org.springframework.security.authenticationManager")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

I don't know wheter is it good solution or isn't, but it's working and spring now inject correct authentication manager.

Answer (score 0):

IANASG (I A Not A Stripes Guru.) I'm assuming Action Bean is a stripes construct?  If it's not managed by spring (instantiated, etc.) then nothing is going to be injected into it because it's a POJO and Spring doesn't know anything about it.

This doesn't look right

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security" />
```

The base-package should be the packages within your code that contain the beans that should be scanned.

Comment: Well, i've got injected into actionbeans other classes by SpringBean. And to Jersey, which I use for RESTful beans i use anotation Inject which didnt worked for authentication manager, but for other beans (for example services) it's working ok.